# Joining two lists with relational operators

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have two lists `liste = {x, -y, y, -z}` and `listv = {1, -2, 3, -4}`, which represent the inequities obtained evaluating `liste - listv <= 0`. How do I reassemble or join those two separate lists into a more readable one having the form `{x <= 1, 2 <= y <= 3, z >= 4}`?

I further require that, when an expression comes with both a lower bound and a upper bound like the `y` above, it should not be written in two separate equalities `y >= 2` and `y <= 3`, but in the more compact form `2 <= y <= 3`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Thread[liste - listv <= 0] // Reduce
```

> ```
> 2 <= y <= 3 && z >= 4 && x <= 1
> ```

```
List @@ %
```

> ```
> {2 <= y <= 3, z >= 4, x <= 1}
> ```

> How do I reorder the inequities in an "alphabetic + numeric" order, such as `{2 <= x1 <= 3, x2 >= 4, z <= 1}`

Assuming there is one variable per inequality and there are no different length variables, e.g. `x, x1, x12` at once, then:

```
#[[Ordering[Cases[#, s_Symbol /; Context[s] =!= "System`", ∞] & /@ #]]] &[
   {2 <= y <= 3, z >= 4, x <= 1}
]
```

> ```
> {x <= 1, 2 <= y <= 3, z >= 4}
> ```

so at the end

```
Composition[
  #[[
    Ordering[
      Cases[
        #, s_Symbol /;  Context[s] =!= "System`", ∞
      ] & /@ #
    ]
  ]] &,
  Apply[List],
  Reduce,
  Thread
  ][liste - listv <= 0]
```

Comment: Can be written directly as `List @@ Reduce @ Thread[liste - listv <= 0]`

Comment: Great answer. If the three variable names I used change to `liste={z, -x1, x1, -x2}`, the answer generated would be `{x2 >= 4, z <= 1, 2 <= x1 <= 3}`. How do I reorder the inequities in an "alphabetic + numeric" order, such as `{2 <= x1 <= 3, x2 >= 4, z <= 1}`?

Comment: @nanjun done, is that what where you after?

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, exactly. I came up with a follow-up question, though. What if the those inequalities involve some user defined functions? For example, I want something like `{2 <= x[1] <= 3, x[2] >= 4, z <= 1}`, where `z` is just a variable, but `x[n_]` is some function I previously defined. How do I just order the list without evaluating my user function  `x[n_]` here?

Comment: @nanjun you can perform all actions inside `Block` and use `HoldForm` to prevent output from evaluation. Here is a minimal example: `f[x_] := x^2; Block[{f}, HoldForm[#] &[f[x] < 0]]`

Answer (score 5):

```
LessEqual @@@ Transpose@{l1, l2} // Reduce
```

> 2 <= y <= 3 && z >= 4 && x <= 1